# FTP getbinaryfile by file extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Net::FTP's `getbinaryfile` functionality to pull in a zip file with FTP. My system is not aware of the full file name, so I would simply like to search the folder for the zip file extension. Usually I would simply input the filename as `*.zip`. This does not seem to work.

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new(domain)
path = "#{Rails.root}/public/ftp/#{self.id}.zip"
ftp.getbinaryfile("*.zip", path)
```

Comment: It's important to remember that FTP is *not* the same as using the command-line and shell. Your FTP client is relying on a server which has different functionality, so wildcards won't work the same way; For instance, we can't get a bunch of files that match a pattern. There are extensions to the FTP protocol that some servers implement, but the client has to sense those, and then be programmed to take advantage of them. The basic commands always work, so become familiar with them, and build on top of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following code to return the zip file name in the FTP folder. Then using the same code as above, I was able to run `getbinaryfile` with the correct zip file name.

```
files = ftp.nlst("*.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to get all zip files (I'm using SFTP but hopefully this will point you in the right direction)

```
Net::SFTP.start(domain, user, :password => 'pass') do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.glob("/yourdirectory","*.zip").each do |file|
    sftp.download!(file, "/local/spot")
  end
end
```